# TSQL - clone records for a day

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I'm working on creating a Lab with a big MSSQL database. 
To simplify the problem, Let's assume that it's for 1 table only (If I can find a better solution, I can do it for all tables)

I have data for 1 day in a table, say between 525k and 630k records.  I want to duplicate the data for different days (create history).

I've already tried different ways and I'm finding it very long. initially the process was taking 91 hours to duplicate 1 day... I brought it down to 16 minutes  to process 1 day (which makes approx. 91 hours to duplicate a year) .   I'm wondering if there is any tool or something made to duplicate data or create a history quickly?

Here's what I have right now:

```
    Declare @iDateCnt int=1,
            @TmpDate datetime,
            @iDate int=365, -- counter to create a years worth of history.
            @DateStart datetime = '2015-12-22'
    Select F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10, getdate() as F11
    into #TMP_Table1
    From Table1 where F1 = @DateStart -- Template Day to be duplicated

While @iDateCnt<=@iDate
Begin 
    Set @TmpDate = @DateStart-@iDateCnt
    Delete from Table1 where F1 = @TmpDate
    Insert into Table1 (F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10, F11)
        Select @TmpDate as F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10, getdate() as F11
        from #Tmp_Table1

    Drop #Tmp_Table1
End
```

Comment: The reason its so slow is you're doing one record at a time in a loop. SQL cannot have any chance to optimize that, it would (most likely) work in seconds as a batch.

Comment: Create a date table (or CTE) that holds one row for each date you want to populate, and then crossjoin to that table instead of running a loop.

Comment: Why are you using a while loop for this? That is the crux of the performance problem. This can be rewritten as a single set based insert.

Comment: @Tab Alleman I think this might be a great idea. But I'm not sure I understand how this would work.  I would delete anything not part of the template date and cross join the dates table and do 1 big insert using the the date as F1 from the date table. right?  Please add as answer, I would vote as the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To formulate my comment into an answer, you would start by creating a table that has a datetime column, with one row for every date that you want to populate with cloned data.   Say we call it `tblDates`.   Then you would just do this to your existing script:

```
Select F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10, getdate() as F11
into #TMP_Table1
From Table1 where F1 = @DateStart -- Template Day to be duplicated

    Insert into Table1 (F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10, F11)
        Select tblDates.DtColumn as F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10, getdate() as F11
        from #Tmp_Table1
        CROSSJOIN tblDates

    Drop #Tmp_Table1
End
```

This will create a copy of all the data in `#TMP_Table1` for each row in `tblDates`, with the date from `tblDates` in the `F1` column (where you were previously using the loop variable).

Comment: Based on your comment It's exactly what I ended up doing.  Thank you.

Comment: the outcome of the duplication of records for a whole year : out of disk space and everything hung.  Since my test for 1 day took 25sec, I'm expecting it to take up to 3hrs for a full year but due to size of the dataset, I'm doubting that this will perform better. I have a feeling that I will need to loop and do chunks at a time but with more disk space, I'll wait and see how the full year insert performs.

Comment: You probably will get better performance looping this solution and breaking it into chunks.  Creating 365 copies of 600k rows...it's going to take a while.   : )

Comment: I also think so.  The problem is that I'm doing this for a whole database and some tables aren't that big and don't need to be broken down.  I have to figure out a way to dynamically decide if data should be inserted by chunks or not.  Not sure how yet.

Answer (score 1):

Doing one insert at a time will always be slow, especially with a heavily indexed table.

Instead you should do this as a single insert, something along the lines of

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '2015-12-22'
DECLARE @endDate = DATEADD(days,365, @startDate)

Insert into Table1 (F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10, F11)        
Select F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10, getdate() 
FROM Table1 where F1 > @startDate AND F1 <= @endDate
```

Comment: @Tmpdate is the date I'm looping on. I don't see the difference here.

Comment: @JohnG - sorry, left `@tmpdata` in by accident. its a simple select from source insert to destination (same table in your case)

Comment: but this won't work as I need to change F1 to have every day of the year.  my template in the table has 525K records with the 2015-12-22 date; I need to copy this set of data for every other day of that year... So F1 taking the value of every other day. I think Tab Alleman's answer using a cross join is the right one.  all you'd be missing in your solution is to add a date table, cross joining it and using that date as F1.

Comment: @JohnG: That sounds kind of odd. What is the actual end result - i.e. use of the data? I can't think of a use case for copying the same data to every day of a year.

Comment: @HardCode We want to simulate deployments, maintenance plans and growth analysis on databases similar in size to the ones that our customers have.